# I can’t create $stateProvider ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm so early for ionic framework, and i'm trying to make mobile apps with ionic.

I was wondering how to change the overall look, if it makes the website quite by < a href="#">, but in ionic how it works (?)

I'm trying to add some code app.js :

```
config(function($stateProvider) {
 $stateProvider

  .state('expense', {
     url: "/app/expense",
     templateUrl: 'templates/add-expense.html'
   })
});
```

this my code index.html :

```
<body ng-app="starter">
   <ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-header bar-dark">
     <button class="button button-clear button-positive">Edit</button>
     <div class="h1 title">23 Desember 20014</div>
     <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right"> </button>
    </ion-header-bar>

 <ion-content>
  <div class="row green">
   <div class="col">Income</div>
   <div class="col price">3,550,000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row expense orange">
   <a class="col" href="#/app/expense">New Expense</a> <!-- try to link templates/add-expense.html -->
   </div>
 </ion-content> 
 </ion-side-menu-content> 

 <ion-side-menu side="right">
   <a menu-close href="#" class="item">Home</a>
 </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
<body>
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your project into plunker

Comment: thanks for reply, this example my work http://plnkr.co/edit/FHBTQJJDXNwX3kmlqNgJ?p=preview ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [updated working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MH5u1k4NXnvr0rGv5hJz?p=preview). I am not expert of the ionic, so just basics are fixed/improved.

One issue is, that the config should be a method of something:

```
// wrong
config(function($stateProvider) {
...
```

The app is having config method

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
...
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('expense', {
      url: "/app/expense",
      templateUrl: 'add-expense.html',
    })      
});
```

Also, I wrapped the content with `<ion-nav-view>`, as a placeholder for the state `expenses` *(it must be injected into some `ui-view=""`  - unnamed anchor)*

But these are few adjustments just to make it running, you should investigate the ionic more, read about it, to understand the concept, because e.g. the add-expsenses.html is not the way...

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MH5u1k4NXnvr0rGv5hJz?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for reply,
oke I started to understand how it can work ( for this case ), 

may i ask again, if I have for a lot of page for apps, whether on each page should be included tag <head><style></style></head> (?) because any page always different colors

Comment: Not an expert of ionic... so just on the basic stuff. You should have one page, one index.html with head and style. THAT is the concept of SPA. Just the views (part of html) are changed with UI-Router, wrapped inside of the ionic elements. But really, spend some time to read through

Comment: Also, there is some link to one ionic plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/I5bvIN3F6yNZg799ig6i?p=preview. It could help to see how ot organize

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with config section , should use this way.

And use   also in html. And remove unused code on "add-expense.html" Use need to add template which you need to show.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('expense', {
      url: "/app/expense",
      templateUrl: 'add-expense.html'
    })

});


function ContentController($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
  $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };
}
```